# How to visualize a series of TimeObject?

Tags: visualization, date-and-time

```
data = Get["http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/data.wl"];
```

[image]

And `data` can access `data["a"]`,`data["b"]`...`data["n"]` and I want to visualize it.
But I can't figure out how to do it.

I find there is a `ClockGauge` function,but it can not support `ClockGauge[data["a"]]`.And clock only have 12 hours per circle,it can not express the true time.

`Histogram[data["a"]]` also generate a blank plot.

So how to do it?

Ps:Using `TimelinePlot` can plot it,but it is difficult to see the effect.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how useful is this, but it does give an alternative view on the data. Note the sorting of the dates before converting to `TimeSeries` objects -- one might be interested in the unsorted view.

```
Multicolumn[
 DateListPlot[
    TimeSeries[Transpose[{Sort@#[[2]], Range[Length[#[[2]]]]}]], 
    PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] & /@ Normal[data]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find DateHistogram can plot it

```
Column[Thread[Keys[data] -> Table[DateHistogram[data[[i]], Quantity[1, "Hours"], ImageSize -> Medium], {i, Length@data}]]]
```

[image]